# Load image from URL to Recyclerview without using picasso

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an app that loads multiple images from the internet. I am using a RecyclerView along with CardView to display my content in a list form.pls help me.i am new for the android.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't want to use picasso? Is [ImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) an option for you?

All you need to do is:

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); // Get singleton instance

// Load image, decode it to Bitmap and display Bitmap in ImageView (or any other view 
//  which implements ImageAware interface)
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```

Comment: first of all i try this method

Comment: i think this code will placed inside the onBindViewHolder(cutomViewHolder viewholder,int position).how can i get the imageuri and image view

Comment: You should be able to get the image view from your customViewHolder (it should have a field which refer to the image view or you can use a simple findViewById for example). About the image uri, it depends from what image do you want to show. Can you clarify on this one?

Comment: Thank u for first one.i need to use multiple image url using array list.Generally i used this url for 100 image"http://www.onethousandpaintings.com/imgs/numbers/number_1.png"

Comment: Ok, then if the appendix "number_1" is the changing part, you can do some string concatenation to make the "1" dynamically change according to the "position" argument that you get from the method signature.

Comment: yes, it change dynamically.........

Comment: is my solution working for you then?

Comment: this causes `NetworkOnMainThreadException` when used inside `onBindViewHolder`